# How to insert a Character every X Characters in a String in Golang?

Tags: string, go, character

**Aim:** to insert a character every x characters in a string in Golang

**Input:** `helloworldhelloworldhelloworld`

**Expected Output:** `hello-world-hello-world-hello-world`

**Attempts**

*Attempt one*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "helloworldhelloworldhelloworld"

    s = strings.Replace(s, "world", ",", -1)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

results in: `hello,hello,hello,`

---

*Attempt two*

1. Count number of characters
2. For loop
3. If X=5 then insert a `-`

---

*Attempt three*

1. Scan combined with join

**Problem**

The reason that attempts two and three do not contain code snippets at the moment is that I am still thinking what approach should be used to insert a character every X characters in a string in Golang.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/HEGbe7radf

This function just inserts '-' each Nth element

```
func insertNth(s string,n int) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    var n_1 = n - 1
    var l_1 = len(s) - 1
    for i,rune := range s {
       buffer.WriteRune(rune)
       if i % n == n_1 && i != l_1  {
          buffer.WriteRune('-')
       }
    }
    return buffer.String()
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/IzcWx771wF

Here's a slightly more general version, that takes arbitrary runes to use as the character to insert.

Answer (score 4):

I feel the following solution is worth mentioning:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var s = "helloworldhelloworldhelloworld"

func main() {
    for i := 5; i < len(s); i += 6 {
        s = s[:i] + "-" + s[i:]
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/aMXOTgiNHf

Answer (score 2):

According to the Go documentation [strings are a read only Slice of bytes.](https://blog.golang.org/slices). With that in mind there is an issue that comes up. What character set are you using? You can see some examples of where things get weird [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263607/how-to-get-a-single-unicode-character-from-string-in-golang) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018545/how-to-index-characters-in-a-golang-string).

Despite the complexity there still is a simple answer

```
s = strings.Replace(s, "hello", "hello-", -1)
s = strings.Replace(s, "world", "world-", -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const s = "helloworldhelloworldhelloworld"

func Attempt1(s string) string {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(\Bhello|\Bworld)`)
    return re.ReplaceAllString(s, "-$1")
}

func Attempt2(s string) string {
    const chunkLen = len("hello")
    out := make([]rune, len(s)+len(s)/chunkLen)
    i, j := 1, 0
    for _, c := range s {
        out[j] = c
        if i == len(s) {
            break
        }
        j++
        if i%chunkLen == 0 {
            out[j] = '-'
            j++
        }
        i++
    }
    return string(out)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Attempt1(s))
    fmt.Println(Attempt2(s))
}
```

[<kbd>Playground link</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/QQ-ccxM4z3)

I should add that while it would be possible to implement
"approach 3" — that "split the source string in chunks of
five characters then join the chunks using the '-' character" one, —
it would still require scanning the source string rune-by-rune as my `Attempt2()` does; so if you squint at it, you'll see that storing
a list of chunks and then joining them is doing more operations for
no real gain (and bigger memory footprint etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you know your string is divisible by 5, then this could also be a solution. Definitely less efficient though than some of the other solutions posted.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(InsertEvery5("HelloWorld", "-"))
}

// Only works if len(str) mod 5 is 0
func InsertEvery5(str string, insert string) string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`.{5}`) // Every 5 chars
    parts := re.FindAllString(str, -1) // Split the string into 5 chars blocks.
    return strings.Join(parts, insert) // Put the string back together
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My take. I needed to add new lines (more than a single character) to long strings to wrap them.

```
func InsertNewLines(s string, n int) string {
    var r = regexp.MustCompile("(.{" + strconv.Itoa(n) + "})")
    return r.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1<wbr />")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-allocating memory and using `copy` is faster than iteration over every single character.

https://go.dev/play/p/NqVYnOJGRLP

```golang
func insertNthCopy(in, sep string, n int) string {
    count := len(in) / n // amount of lines to split
    split := make([]byte, len(in)+len(sep)*count)
    i, s := 0, 0

    for ; i < count*n; i, s = i+n, s+n+len(sep) {
        copy(split[s:], in[i:i+n])
        copy(split[s+n:], sep)
    }

    copy(split[s:], in[i:]) // copy remainder if any

    return string(split)
}
```

About six times faster than the accepted answer with provided sample string:

```
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Benchmark_insertNthCopy
Benchmark_insertNthCopy-8       12404311            85.11 ns/op
Benchmark_insertNth
Benchmark_insertNth-8            2269458           524.5 ns/op
```