# How to create a 0x appended hex string from a hex string for each byte of hex characters in golang?

Tags: go

Using the following as a starting point I was able to get something working.

[How to insert a Character every X Characters in a String in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633168/how-to-insert-a-character-every-x-characters-in-a-string-in-golang)

But I want to know if there is an idiomatic way to write golang for what I wan to do, which is the output of the first fmt.Println shown below:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func insertStringInto(s string, interval int, sep string) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    before := interval - 1
    last := len(s) - 1
    for i, char := range s {
        buffer.WriteRune(char)
        if i%interval == before && i != last {
            buffer.WriteString(sep)
        }
    }
    return buffer.String()
}


func main() {
    fmt.Println("0x" + insertStringInto("01234567891011121314151617181920", 2, ", 0x"))

    fmt.Println(insertStringInto("01234567891011121314151617181920", 2, ", 0x"))
}
```

Produces the following:

```
0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x20
01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x20
```

Link to play.golang.org below:

https://play.golang.org/p/TvLFAKsrcCB

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how idiomatic this is but re-slicing of strings is often used for this sort of thing. Also `strings.builder` was introduced recently.

```
func insertInto(s string, interval int, prefix, sep string) string {
    sb := strings.Builder{}
    sb.Grow((len(s)/interval+1)*(interval+len(prefix)+len(sep)))

    first := true
    for i := 0; i < len(s)/interval; i++ {
        if first {
            first = false
        } else {
            sb.WriteString(sep)
        }
        sb.WriteString(prefix)
        sb.WriteString(s[i*interval :(i+1)*interval])
    }
    return sb.String()
}

...
    print(insertInto("0123456789101112131415161718192", 2, "0x", ", "))
```

Note that this does not try to validate that the string only contains hex digits.  It also assumes that it is a multiple of `interval`, but could be easily tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func AnotherWay(s string, after int, sep string) string {
    ex, _ := regexp.Compile(`([0-9]{2})`)
    return strings.TrimSuffix(ex.ReplaceAllString(s, sep+"$1, "), ", ")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(AnotherWay("01234567891011121314151617181920", 2, "0x"))
}
```

Comment: Does this allow for hex digits [A-Fa-f] ?

Comment: I think you just need to change the regex.